# Search options on the check-in history in Visual Studio

Tags: search, visual-studio-2012, history, checkin

I'm trying to identify some milestones (which date we introduced important features on the website) by viewing the check-in history in Visual Studio. However it annoys me that I can't search the check-in comments, or filter check-ins by a specific user.

Is there a plugin or sth where I can have more search option to filter the check-in history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Source Control Explorer, then on the menu bar, choose File, Source Control, Find, Find Changesets.

The Find Changesets dialog box appears with the some of the options you require such as by user.

Visual Studio docs: [Find and view changesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/find-view-changesets)